# Importing data from an HTML file (with embedded JavaScript) into MySQL database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, domdocument

Please who knows how to import this content into a mysql database?

I want to get the data from this HTML into the database. I have a 5000 of such files and I want to import them. The problem is that there is an embedded JavaScript in the file. Please have a look at the HTML content at the bottom of this message.

I have had a look at `simple_html_dom` but I can’t figure out how to get it right.

**Thanks in advance.**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Quanta Plus">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>


<div id="company_record">
    <div class="comp_record_left">
            <H1>Company name</H1>
            <b>Contact:</b> Contactpersoon naam<br/>
            <b>Address:</b> Adresstraatname 43<br/>
            <b>Zipcode:</b> 4444 ZC<br/>
            <b>City:</b> Placename<br/>
            <b>Email:</b> 
<script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>
 <!--
 var prefix = 'm&#97;&#105;lt&#111;:';
var suffix = '';
var attribs = '';
var path = 'hr' + 'ef' + '=';
var encdd = 'm&#101;m&#97;&#105;l&#97;dr' + '&#64;';
encdd = encdd + 'h&#111;tm&#97;&#105;l' + '&#46;' + 'c&#111;m';
 encdd = encdd + 'h&#111;tm&#97;&#105;l' + '&#46;' + 'c&#111;m';
 document.write( '<a ' + path + '\'' + prefix + encdd + suffix + '\'' + attribs + '>' );
 document.write( enc );
 document.write( '<\/a>' );
 //-->
 </script><script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>
 <!--
 document.write( '<span style=\'display: none;\'>' );
 //-->
 </script>Dit e-mail adres is beschermd tegen spambots. U heeft Javascript nodig om het te kunnen zien.
 <script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>
 <!--
 document.write( '</' );
 document.write( 'span>' );
 //-->
 </script>
            <br/><br/>
            <img src="/images/4000001_img.jpg" alt="Company name image alt"/><br/><br/><br/>
            <b>Comments:</b> 
                Our comppany is wonderfull this is our services<br />
                service 1 <br />
                service 1 <br />
                service 1 <br />
                service 1 <br />
    </div>
    <div class="comp_record_right">
            <div class="rating_block">
                <p class="item">
                    Company: <span class="fn">Company name </span>
                </p>
                <span class="rating">
                    Rating: <span class="average">5</span> (scale to  
                <span class="best">10</span>)
                </span>
                <span> After <span class="count">10</span> days.</span>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If what you're after is to parse the JavaScript and have the evaluated DOM to insert into a database, this is probably not the way to go. Have a look at something like http://simile.mit.edu/wiki/Crowbar instead.

Comment: just want to get the record into the database including the email address in it ..  don't see how to use Crowbar for that .. thanks a lot for you time ..

Comment: @GABRIELCIRSTEA simple_html_dom looks good for exploring the dom, you can easily get any node with specific class. However using it suppose you can list all your 5000 files easily, and have a consistent content across them.

Answer (score 0):

If you know a way for listing all your 5000 files, and have a consistant content across them, you can use **simple_html_dom** as simply as :

```
// assuming you include that lib
// $files contains file pathes
for($files as $file) {
    $html = file_get_html($file);
    $text = $html->find('div.comp_record_left')->innerText();
    // here you need to parse...
    // or you may want to find more specific elements in.
}
```

This code is far from a complete solution, but it could point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks !! My problem is getting the email address and other fields .. the h1 as company name I already have .. would not be a problem if any field had his own class or id .. but :-) anyway very much thank you